# Adding a static row to the ListView populated by OrmliteCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, ormlite

I've got an Activity where my user can choose from a list of objects from the database. So, I have a ListView being populated by my `OrmliteCursorAdapter` which works very well. They can choose from A, B, C, D, etc items from the db.

So, the ListView currently has 4 rows and looks like:

```
A
B
C
D
```

However, I want to have the first item in the listView be "None" so if they had previously chosen B, but they want to clear out that selection, they can tap "None".

I would like the ListView to have 5 rows and look like:

```
None
A
B
C
D
```

Short of just rewriting my own complete Adapter wrapper around the `OrmliteCursorAdapter` (or `Cursor` subclass to pass to the Ormlite one) so that I can shift all the results, is there any way I can insert that static row above all of the fetched results?